# Could not load file for SmartsheetClient through Smartsheet SDK C#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I'm trying to use Smartsheet API's sdk in C# to get rows from a smartsheet and save them elsewhere. When trying to initialize the SmartsheetClient I get a FileNotFoundException. I have used my access token in Postman and it works. Do I need to specify anything about the client or token in order to initialize?

I'm working in C# using Visual Studio (community 2019) I've installed the smartsheet-csharp-sdk NuGet package. I've looked through the Smartsheet API documentation and succesfully executed the process manually through postman.

```
//using System
//using Smartsheet.Api;
//using Smartsheet.Api.Models;
//using Smartsheet.Api.OAuth;
//using System.Net.Http;
//using System.Net;
//using System.Web;
//using System.Web.Http;

Token token = new Token();
token.AccessToken = "{my access token}";


SmartsheetClient smartsheet = 
    new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();
```

I expected the SmartsheetClient to initialize so that I could use it for getting data within the sheets, but instead it throws an error.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are missing dependencies. You could look in the References section in Visual Studio to see the required assemblies. There could be a warning showing what is missing. You could consider re-installing the SDK to make sure you have all of the necessary dependencies installed.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem now.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad to hear it.